# Alterar tamanho máximo de vídeo suportado por servidor

Tags: wamp, cross-browser, html5-video

Estava testando um vídeo na minha pagina, só que me deparei com um problema....

A linha do meu código é basicamente só isso:

```
<video id="video" src="arquivo.mp4" controls="true" />
```

A resolução do vídeo esta com o tamanho de cada frame definido em `1920w x 1080h`. O video esta no formato `.mp4`. Ou seja, o vídeo é consideravelmente grande.

Testei nos seguintes browsers:

### Firefox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não executa nem som, nem vídeo, e ainda me aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> A mídia http://localhost/arquivo.mp4 não pôde ser decodificada.

### Chrome

Executa o som, mas o vídeo em si não aparece.

### Opera

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Reduzi a visualização em 50% para poder caber todo o vídeo na tela*
Executa tanto o som, quanto o vídeo.

Safari e Explorer eu nem testei...
Minha duvida é se existe um requisito máximo(e qual é?) de tamanho do vídeo para execução nesses browsers.
Ou se isso vai da configuração do servidor, e se for, como alterar para que possa ser executado?

---

### Edit

Como comentado pelo @GiancarloAbelGiulian, uma informação adicional: estou utilizando o `wamp server` v. 2.5.

---

### Edit(2)

Na hora estava testando apenas localmente, acabei esquecendo de jogar no servidor, o problema ocorre no `http` também.

Comment: Veja se esse link pode lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328401/html5-how-to-stream-large-mp4-files.

Comment: Marcelo existem vários codecs, talvez possa nem ser o tamanho, mas sim a codificação, não tenho certeza, pode ser até problema no audio. Estranho que você disse que usa o wamp, mas o erro apresentado foi com o protocolo `file:///`. O problema ocorre no http também?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento atualizei a pergunta, o erro esta ocorrendo no protocolo http também...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo suas informações, pode ser que haja um destes dois problemas:

1. Falha na decodificação do vídeo em MP4 pelo navegador; ou
2. Falha na transferência do vídeo pelo servidor devido ao tamanho do
   arquivo.

Por isso apresentarei duas possíveis soluções:

**HIPÓTESE 1 - CORRIGIR A DECODIFICAÇÃO DO ARQUIVO DE VÍDEO**

Antes de mexer nas configurações do seu servidor WAMP, temos que ter certeza que não há problemas de codificação no próprio arquivo de vídeo.

Todo vídeo comprimido (AVI, MPG, MP4) sempre gera dentro de sí um "index" de metadados para busca e sincronia do áudio e vídeo. Este "index" serve para que os players possam avançar e retroceder o vídeo de forma rápida e eficiente, sem travar ou perder a sincronia entre os streams durante a reprodução. Quando não existe este "index", ou ele tem falhas, os programas travam ao tentar exibir o arquivo ou tentam criar um "index" temporário para os metadados do arquivo, só rodando o mesmo após completar esta tarefa. Quanto maior o arquivo mais tempo levará para o vídeo rodar.

Os vídeos em MP4 têm o problema de gerar este "index" de metadados somente no FINAL DO ARQUIVO fazendo com que a maioria dos navegadores tenham que baixar TODO o conteúdo multimídia para começar a exibí-lo (isto, se não travarem).

Para resolver este problema, vamos usar um pequeno programa chamado "My MP4Box Gui" que consegue ajustar os arquivos MP4 para transmissão via internet, criando o "index" de metadados no início do vídeo. Basta seguir os passos abaixo:

1. Baixe e instale o My MP4Box GUI
   (http://www.videohelp.com/software/My-MP4Box-GUI).
2. Abra o My MP4Box GUI e selecione "Options -> Hint For RTP/RTSP" (é
   esta opção que habilita a reconstrução do index de metadados na
   frente do arquivo).
3. Clique em "Add" e selecione o vídeo MP4 que você deseja tornar
   compatível para streaming via servidor (WAMP).
4. Clique em "Save As..." e escolha uma pasta e um nome para salvar o
   arquivo.
5. Por fim, clique em "Mux" e aguarde o novo vídeo MP4 otimizado ser
   gerado. O programa leva cerca de 1 minuto para recriar o index de um
   vídeo com 150MB.

**HIPÓTESE 2 - CONFIGURAR O SERVIDOR WAMP PARA ACEITAR VÍDEOS MAIORES**

Caso a hipótese acima não tenha resultados, então o problema deve ser em relação a transmissão do vídeo pelo servidor.

Geralmente, o WAMP Server limita por padrão o tamanho dos arquivos de vídeo aceitos para upload e transmissão, a fim de garantir sua eficiência na exibição dos arquivos.

Para configurar o Servidor WAMP para aceitar vídeos maiores que o padrão, siga estes passos:

1. Vá até a pasta onde está instalado o WampServer (geralmente em
   C:/Wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/bin) e abra o arquivo "ini.php" via
   bloco de notas.
2. Aberto o arquivo, dê um Ctrl + F para achar as seguintes linhas:

   `post_max_size = 8M`   e altere para:  `post_max_size = 750M` e

   `upload_max_filesize = 2M`  e altere para:  `upload_max_filesize = 750M`

Com estas dicas, espero ter lhe ajudado!

Comment: Eu testei suas soluções, mas nenhuma das duas funcionou...

Comment: Poxa... Vou ver se consigo lhe sugerir alguma outra forma. Entretanto, preciso de mais informações: você disse que testou esse vídeo, primeiro, carregando ele direto nos navegadores através de uma página em HTML5, certo? Se você simplesmente arrasta o vídeo para a barra de endereços dos navegadores (http://... ou file://...) ele também dá esse erro? Eu ví que no Firefox existe um aviso que "o arquivo está corrompido" mas no Opera roda normal. É quase certo que possa ser um problema no próprio vídeo. Você gravou com qual equipamento (iPhone, câmera Canon...)? Qual o CODEC do vídeo (MediaInfo)?

Comment: Ah... se você conseguir postar o vídeo (ou um trecho dele) para eu fazer download eu poderia verificar no meu próprio sistema, para lhe dar informações mais precisas.

Comment: Puts, consegui resolver, tinha haver com o codec mesmo...., vou aceitar sua resposta porque ela me ajudou a encontrar o problema, porem vou criar uma resposta mais sucinta de qual foi a solução que eu usei